# How to connect to password enabled BLE sensor?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I'm using Minew S1 Humidity and Temperature sensor with raspberry Pi, initially this sensor is password enabled, so how can I connect it to Humidity Sensor with Raspberry Pi using bluetoothctl or gatttool.

Edited:

```
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #52 [hci0] 23.727179
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x0027
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                   #53 [hci0] 23.775948
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2


> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                           #54 [hci0] 32.502249
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 32.502320
        LE Address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Reason: Connection terminated by remote host (0x03)
```

Thank you

Comment: How far have you come by using bluetoothctl?

Comment: @Emil I'm able to connect the sensor with bluetoothctl but the connection does not persist for long time, even I also tried to connect using nrf app, there also I face same problem connection does not persist for long time, the duration of connection is around 10 seconds, but with BeaconSet+ app the connection persists for long time.

Comment: The sensor probably expects a password via a custom protocol to one of its characteristics. The BeaconSet+ app does this automatically and the sensor stays connected. Without the documentation, you can only try using a BLE sniffer to reverse engineer the protocol

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I captured packets of android and raspberry pi and compared, there is no difference in ATT protocol but while establishing connection with HCI_command, android mobile sends "LE create Extended connection" and Raspberry Pi sends "LE create connection"

Comment: What is the disconnection reason? Is it "Connection terminated by remote device" or "Connection Timeout"?

Comment: @Emil I don't know perfectly but I think it's from my sensor, check the log I provided on post once

Comment: Yes your remote device forcefully disconnects. We can only speculate why it does that. You would have to read its documentation or reverse engineer its protocol to get any further.